# View files in j2ee web application using fancybox and google doc viewer

Tags: file, servlets, jakarta-ee, fancybox-3

I have a java servlet that serves files from s3. These files can be either image, pdf or doc/docx. I have to implement a feature in my web application to display these files in google doc viewer.

In my case, I am not able to send content so that google doc viewer reads it and displays the file. (when shouldDownload == Binary.YES).

This the code I have that downloads the file from s3 and set it in my bean class -

```
ApplicantzFileModel document = (ApplicantzFileModel) MongoSelectRogueModel
                .selectOneById(ApplicantzFileModel.class, id);
        Binary shouldDownload = Binary.valueOf(download);
        if (document != null) {
            if (shouldDownload == Binary.YES) {
                docBean.fileStream = document.downloadFileStream();
                docBean.fileName = document.getFileName();
                docBean.isFileDownloadResponse = true;
            } else {
                File file = document.downloadFile();
                if (file != null) {
                    String content = null;
                    content = FileHandler.read(file);
                    if (content != null) {
                        docBean.fileContent = content;
                        docBean.fileName = document.getFileName();
                    }
                }
            }
            docBean.actionSuccess = true;
            docBean.isFileContentResponse = true;
        }
```

This is the code in my doGet/doPost to serve the response -

```
if (bean.isFileDownloadResponse) {
                    OutputStream responseOutputStream;
                    try {
                        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + bean.fileName);
                        responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                        int len = -1;
                        while ((len = bean.fileStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                            responseOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        responseOutputStream.flush();
                        responseOutputStream.close();
                        bean.fileStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    response.setContentType("application/msword");
                    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + bean.fileName);
                    responseStr = bean.fileContent;
                    PrintWriter writer = null;
                    try {
                        writer = response.getWriter();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (writer != null) {
                        writer.println(responseStr);
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                    }
                }
```

And this is the html code in my frontend to open google doc viewer in fancybox -

```
"<a data-fancybox="" data-type="iframe" data-src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsomeserver.com%2Fapplication%2Fdocument%3Faction%3Dget%26id%3Dsomeid%26download%3DYES&amp;embedded=true" href="javascript:void(0);" data-doc-id="someid">My Link</a>"
```

Or more specifically, google doc viewer url that opens up -

```
var innerurl = encodeURIComponent('http://someserver.com/application/document?action=get&id='+this.docId+'&download=YES');
        this.docUrl = 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+innerurl+'&embedded=true';
```

I am not able to open the word or pdf document in my fancybox. Can someone please suggest what to do to serve files via Java.

Comment: Are you able to display your page in iframe tag? If no, then you should find out why in the first place. If yes, then it just should work.

Comment: ok. let me try that. thanks.

Comment: @Janis: it is not working in an iframe as well. What am I missing here. I am getting doc file contents on Java side. I am just not able to send it to browser so that it can render the file. I am also able to download a doc/pdf file. just not able to render it.

Comment: To render PDF files, you would need to use external library, for example, https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ Maybe these will help for docs - https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264684/embed-google-docs-pdf-viewer-in-iframe/2311327

Comment: so, just to confirm, am I sending response correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I have not included docs in iframe, therefore I can not help with that (I do not know if that is even possible), but pdf.js works fine as you can see here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/RYXOeK?editors=1000