# Google Docs Viewer

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

is free or commercial Google Docs Viewer?

- google Viewer API: https://docs.google.com/viewer
- my example file: https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/298/docs/ir211wk12sample.xls

together

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/298/docs/ir211wk12sample.xls" title="preview my file on nav "></iframe>
```

Does it have documentation?

could like to use in my web app but I need documentation or price or limited use?

Comment: As far as I know it's free, there is also an excel module.

Comment: Hey! Google does not have a Viewer API so would you mind stating what exactly do you mean by Google Viewer API?

Comment: or what is this: https://docs.google.com/viewer ? it has limited use or is commercial, where can I see de documentation?

Comment: The link you have shared returns a 400 bad request response; are you using an extension with this name perhaps?

Comment: see my example: whe you add the file work! https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/298/docs/ir211wk12sample.xls

Comment: Dec 2022 - Example that works here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74815732/984471

Answer (score 3):

The only API from Google which interacts with a file in your Drive is Google Drive API and sadly, there is no such thing as Docs Viewer API.

In fact, the "Docs Viewer" is merely a URL which allows you to preview a document while passing the link of a file to it.

I have taken the opportunity to report this on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209969101) and I suggest you star it as any updates regarding this will be posted there.

Comment: see it https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be#gistcomment-2310091