# Searching embedded Google Document using URL parameters

Tags: sql, google-sheets, url, google-api, google-docs

There is no official documentation for the URL parameters for the Google Doc Viewer. The best related question seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695365/query-google-spreadsheet-with-url-parameters). The syntax for querying is (allegedly) close to SQL, but I cannot for the life of me get it correct.

Example of my implementation:

```
<iframe
  src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true`}
/>
```

My goal is to use a parameter in the URL to search for a *keyword* or *sentence* in the document. I can't seem to get **&tq=** or **&q=** to work.

[Google Docs Live Demo](https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://podcasts.ceu.edu/sites/podcasts.ceu.edu/files/sample.doc)

```
`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true}&q=sarcastic`
`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true}&tq=sarcastic`
`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true}&search=sarcastic`
`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true}&find=sarcastic`
`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true/gviz/tq?tq=SELECT%20*%20where%20B%20contains%20%22sarcastic%22`
`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presignedS3url}&embedded=true/gviz/q?q=SELECT%20*%20where%20B%20contains%20%22sarcastic%22`
```

Comment: `Google Docs Live Demo` this doesn't work

Comment: Related question: [Google Docs Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70292845/1330560) Read the comments as well as the answer.